# PowerShell Outlook Advanced Search Complete Event

Tags: powershell, outlook, advanced-search

In a PowerShell script, I want to do some research in Windows local mails.

I have the following script :

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null

$outlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application;

$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");

Function Get-OutlookInbox {

    $accountsList = $namespace.Folders

    $query = "Test"
    $filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '"+$query+"'"

    foreach($account in $accountsList) {
        write-host "SEARCHING IN MAILBOX : " $account.name

        $scope = $account.FolderPath

        $search = $outlook.AdvancedSearch("'$scope'", $filter, $True)

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        
        foreach ($result in $search.Results) {
            $result.Subject
            $result.ReceivedTime
            $result.SenderName
        }

    }

$inbox = Get-OutlookInbox

$inbox
```

It works well thanks to the `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` as the `$outlook.AdvancedSearch` function is asynchronous, I don't really like this way of developing, a bit crappy.

I would like to use [AdvancedSearchComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearchcomplete) Event but I don't know how to use it in PowerShell, and the documentation is for VBA. I'm not very good at PowerShell development, I don't find a way to do it.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution by myself, I post it below, it may be useful to someone in the future :

I used PowerShell [Register-ObjectEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-6) to subscribe to AdvancedSearchComplete event

See my updated script :

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$outlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application;
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $outlook -EventName "AdvancedSearchComplete" -Action {
    Write-Host "ADVANCED SEARCH COMPLETE" $Args.Scope

    if ($Args.Results) {  
        foreach ($result in $Args.Results) {
            write-host "=================================================="
            write-host $result.Subject
            write-host $result.ReceivedTime
            write-host $result.SenderName
            write-host "=================================================="
        }
    }
}

Function Get-OutlookInbox {

    $accountsList = $namespace.Folders

    $query = "Test"
    $filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%"+$query+"%'"

    foreach($account in $accountsList) {
        $scope = $account.FolderPath

        $search = $outlook.AdvancedSearch("'$scope'", $filter, $True)

    }
}

Get-OutlookInbox
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the question and the answer! The code helped a lot!